# How show which commit changed which line in diff

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to show information in diff (or similar tool for git) which line in file was changed by which commit.

Comment: `git blame <file>` prints information for each line in `<file>`, including a short SHA of the commit that last changed each line. That's probably what you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `git blame` command: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame